# Ângulo dentro de um raio google maps

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, google-maps, front-end, maps

Estou com um projeto utilizando o google maps, onde recebo as informações latlng (que irá criar um marcador nessa localização), além de raio e azimute, sabendo que o ângulo será sempre de 60°. Como consigo formar um ângulo com o azimute, dentro de um raio que foi criado com google.maps.Circle em torno do marcador?

Espero ter conseguido expressar minha dúvida, para exemplificar melhor estou deixando uma imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu problema foi resolvido através desse cálculo matemático:

```
var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, latlng1) / 1000;
var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, latlng2) / 1000;

var calcRaio = raio / 1000;

        for (var i = (azimute - angulo / 2) ; i <= (azimute + angulo / 2) ; i += 2) {
            var pint = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat() + (calcRaio / latConv * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180)), latlng.lng() + (calcRaio / lngConv * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)));
            points.push(pint);
        }
            map.addPolygon('black', '#0000FF', points, 99999); //Cria o setor
```